# Confusion with SHA-1 in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I want to know what SHA-1 I need to write in this window:

[image]

Is it the one that I see on the signinReport inside Android Studio, as shown here:
[image]

Or, this is the SHA-1 I need to generate according to this tutorial:
[Authenticating Your Client](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)

Or they are the same one?

Also, when I try to follow their tutorial, via command line, I just, can't get it to work, what am I doing wrong:

[image]

Totally confused, would love to get clarification

Comment: This is is true signinReport inside Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use sha1 key given in studio like below image**[image]

> Or You can find using command also like below (Open **CMD** and hit below commands)

For Debug mode:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

for Release mode:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}
```

example:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\MG\Desktop\test.jks -alias test
```

Comment: So the cmd is a way to FIND the existing Android Studio key?  Another thing: Where do I run this command? because when I copy-paste your code in the Java bin folder, I get `keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist`

Comment: @TTnote, you need to run above command on command prompt, no need to go in java folder. Just open cmd and run above command